# Magento 1.9.4 Shipment PDF

Tags: magento-1.9

I wanted to display only the product name on the shipment pdf. I assume I need to edit the below section from shipment.php and I tried `$item->getName()` but it didn't work

How can i do this ?

```
foreach ($shipment->getAllItems() as $item) {               
    if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
        continue;
    }
    /* Draw item */
    $this->_drawItem($item,$page, $order);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the following class:

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Shipment/Default.php

```
/**
 * Draw item line
 */
public function draw()
{
    $item   = $this->getItem();
    $pdf    = $this->getPdf();
    $page   = $this->getPage();
    $lines  = array();

    // draw Product name
    $lines[0] = array(array(
        'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($item->getName(), 60, true, true),
        'feed' => 100,
    ));

    // draw QTY
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text'  => $item->getQty()*1,
        'feed'  => 35
    );

    // draw SKU
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text'  => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($this->getSku($item), 25),
        'feed'  => 565,
        'align' => 'right'
    );

    // Custom options
    $options = $this->getItemOptions();
    if ($options) {
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            // draw options label
            $lines[][] = array(
                'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split(strip_tags($option['label']), 70, true, true),
                'font' => 'italic',
                'feed' => 110
            );

            // draw options value
            if ($option['value']) {
                $_printValue = isset($option['print_value'])
                    ? $option['print_value']
                    : strip_tags($option['value']);
                $values = explode(', ', $_printValue);
                foreach ($values as $value) {
                    $lines[][] = array(
                        'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($value, 50, true, true),
                        'feed' => 115
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $lineBlock = array(
        'lines'  => $lines,
        'height' => 20
    );

    $page = $pdf->drawLineBlocks($page, array($lineBlock), array('table_header' => true));
    $this->setPage($page);
}
```

**Note:** Don't modify core file.

Comment: Hi Sohel thanks for your reply, where does the getAllItems() method comes from. foreach ($shipment->getAllItems() as $item)

Comment: Yes, that comes from app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.php::getPdf

Comment: Hello just one more question how to get the current order increment id on the shipment.php page

Comment: $order = $shipment->getOrder(); $order->getIncrementId();